# How to make the text looks like keyboard icon in SuperUser thread

Tags: discussion

Some thread like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/113103/how-can-i-move-around-the-bash-commandline-efficiently) can make text looks like keyboard icon. I didn't see in the [edit help](https://superuser.com/editing-help). Can anyone let me know how to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>ABC</kbd> would be <kbd>ABC</kbd> however it doesn't show up correctly on Meta.

FWIW, a [standing question on meta.stackoverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36785/could-the-kbd-tag-be-added-to-the-stackoverflow-editing-help) has been open since January 23rd asking for it be added to the editing help.